# Publishing a common workspace setup

Tags: eclipse, svn, process, ibm-rad

I want to set up certain configurations and preferences in IBM RAD (or say eclipse) so that a big team will be able to use the set-up already done. this would reduce the inconsistencies and rework effort in the team.

Preferably I want to keep that in subversion.

Right now, when created a workspace in my personal desktop and added it to SVN, everytime my team mates check it out obviously the .metadata and other eclipse internal files change based on their input.

Is there a standard practice/process to publish a common workspace setting in RAD/Eclipse?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are probably 2 things that matter most when getting yourself or someone else a new workspace.  Getting the preferences set up, and checking out the appropriate source code.

1a) you can set up a workspace, and then export all the preferences.  That provides a eclipse preference file that can be imported into a new workspace

1b) use project specific preferences where possible, as those will get checked into your SCM

2) the projects you work on can exported to a [Team Project Set File](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-cvs-project-set.htm).  That can be imported  into a new workspace.

Check them all into a releng project in your SCM.  In this context, a [releng](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/e4/releng/org.eclipse.e4.ui.releng/) project is just a project that has all of the build information in it.    Then a new workspace setup involves checkout out the releng project, and importing the PSF and the preferences file.

Comment: will lit be possible to provide/direct me to a link material where this is explained? I tried searching some posts on team project set files and releng project did not get much help. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Or have a look at Workspace Mechanic for Eclipse: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/

Comment: Workspace Mechanic could be the thing you need. On the other hand, if you have a shared file system, there might be an even simpler way to share common preferences.

Comment: Workspace mechanic works very well when you have a shared directory will all the common settings. You just have to add the directory to the list of source directories of WM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Websphere RAD 7.5 it allows you to export a backup of your server profile preferences. So all of that configuration for databases and classpath can be backed up. I would try deploying that to your team and see if that helps.

Right click on the server, then click Server Configuration> Backup .

Hopefully that does the trick.